# Change string in array into object

Tags: javascript, arrays

Im trying to figure out how to change the string into an object. Then I want to take that object and insert it into the array and also removing the string from the array. Any Ideas on how to do this? So far im mapping through the array getting the string.

```js
searchTerms.map(term => {
            if(term.length > 25) {
                const trimmedSearchTerm = term.substring(0,25) + '...';
                const obj = {
                    value: term,
                    trimmedValue: trimmedSearchTerm,
                    icon: 'search',
                    removable: true,
                };
                return searchTerms.push(obj);
                
            } else if(term === "Last 500"){
                const obj = {
                    value: term,
                    trimmedValue: term,
                    icon: 'date_range',
                    removable: false,
                }
                return searchTerms.push(obj)
            } else {
                term = {
                    value: term,
                    trimmedValue: term,
                    icon: 'search',
                    removable: true,
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: You are returning `term` only when `length > 25`, you will end up with many undefined in your array. Not sure what the expected result should be here.

Comment: im getting ["test"]. I want to change that and return [{value: term,
                    trimmedValue: term,
                    icon: 'search',
                    removable: true}]

Comment: I was just testing it with sending a string larger then 25 characters

Comment: You can use JSON.parse() to change string into a JSON object.

Comment: I dont want to change it into json

Answer (score 1):

I believe you just forgot to return the value for each conditionals. Here is a working example

```js
let searchTerms = ["test1", "1234567891011121314151617181920", "Last 500"]

const mappedTerms = searchTerms.map(term => {
    let mappedTerm;
    if(term.length > 25) {
        const trimmedSearchTerm = term.substring(0,25) + '...';
        mappedTerm = {
            value: term,
            trimmedValue: trimmedSearchTerm,
            icon: 'search',
            removable: true,
        };
    } else if(term === "Last 500"){
        mappedTerm = {
            value: term,
            trimmedValue: term,
            icon: 'date_range',
            removable: false,
        }
    } else {
        mappedTerm = {
            value: term,
            trimmedValue: term,
            icon: 'search',
            removable: true,
        }
    }
    
    return mappedTerm;
});

console.log(mappedTerms);
```